# How to call a function of a route inside another route?

Tags: node.js, express

There is a function defined in a route `polygone.js` :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
...
function transformPolygoneFromDbToText(polygoneArrayTxt, cb) {
    var sommets = JSON.parse(polygoneArrayTxt) , ret = "" , separator = "";
    if (polygoneArrayTxt != "") {
        async.eachOf(sommets, function (sommet, position, cb_) {
            var point = JSON.parse(sommet);
            var longitude = point[0], latitude = point[1];
            ret += separator + longitude + " " + latitude;
            separator = ",";
            cb_();
        }, function () {
            cb(ret);
        });
    }
    else
        cb("");
}

module.exports = router;
```

I want to call the function `transformPolygoneFromDbToText` from another `route`. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the function `transformPolygoneFromDbToText` if you have any dependencies then move it to a separate file so that if you can reuse it anywhere you what.

create a file name utils.js

```
function transformPolygoneFromDbToText(polygoneArrayTxt, cb) {
    var sommets = JSON.parse(polygoneArrayTxt) , ret = "" , separator = "";
    if (polygoneArrayTxt != "") {
        async.eachOf(sommets, function (sommet, position, cb_) {
            var point = JSON.parse(sommet);
            var longitude = point[0], latitude = point[1];
            ret += separator + longitude + " " + latitude;
            separator = ",";
            cb_();
        }, function () {
            cb(ret);
        });
    }
    else
        cb("");
}

module.exports = { transformPolygoneFromDbToText }
```

and import like below in route file and export the route to use it in app.js or index.js

```
const { formatErrorResponse } = require('./utils');
```